# Pattern matching with type annotations

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#tuple-pattern, there is this example of a pattern with a type annotation:

> Patterns can have type annotations. These behave like other type annotations and guide inference like other type annotations. Parentheses are required around type annotations in patterns. The following code shows a pattern that has a type annotation.
>
> ```
> let detect1 x =
>       match x with
>       | 1 -> printfn "Found a 1!"
>       | (var1 : int) -> printfn "%d" var1
>   detect1 0
>   detect1 1
> ```

The type annotation `(var1 : int)` is redundant because the literal `1` in the previous pattern establishes the type unambiguously.

Is there any case in which a type annotation such as this would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even when you use type annotation in function parameters, you are using type annotation in patterns too. F# pattern matching works even on function parameters (`let` binding in general).

So, as usual, type annotation is useful when we want to enforce the type immediately instead of relying on the type inference. We can have many places to put type annotation to achieve the same result. Just choose the place that is most convenient for the situation. Consider example below:

```
let detect2 (x : int option) =
    match x with
    | Some y -> ...
    | None -> ...
```

We can write shorter:

```
let detect2 x =
    match x with
    | Some (y : int)
    | None -> ...
```

In this situation we should prefer the later one.

Comment: This is a good answer, which leads me to another question that should either be asked separately or (I suspect rather) left alone because it is a matter of opinion or style.  The question is this: my inclination would be to annotate the function parameter `x` instead of the pattern variable `y` (that is: `let detect2 (x : int) =`).  Is there a reason to prefer applying the annotation to the pattern variable?

Comment: Yes you can just add type annotation for `x`, but should be `let detect2 (x : int option) =`. As you can see `int option` is longer than `int` right? For more complicated examples, we will see significant difference.

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked the fact that it's an option.  Thanks.  I would generalize this to say that the pattern annotation can be useful if you are deconstructing some value with a complex type and you don't want to have to annotate the complex type.  I think that answer satisfies my question.  I'll accept this in a day or so but I want to leave it open for now to encourage others to add other use cases if there are any.

Comment: Actually when you write `let detect2 (x : int option)` you are using type annotation in patterns too. F# pattern matching works even on function parameters (`let` binding in general).

Comment: That too is a good point, and I should have thought of it myself because I was actually looking at that page in the first place because I was unfamiliar with the record pattern, and I wanted to use it *in a let binding.*